# can i check content of values that have been push_back to a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to check the content and display the frequency of each value in the vector. Is that possible?

Comment: What, no language tag? and even the pastebin doc isn't syntax-colored either...... :(

Comment: Sorry its in c++ and i just colored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use one of the containers, e.g. vector.
you could `push_back` all the moves into this vector until home is reached.

The size of this vector will be the number of moves.
You can setup a counter array[400] for counting the number of moves into same coordinates.

```
For each move,
    - `push_back` the move into the vector.
    - increment the counter array indexed by [the move].
```

Comment: This seems to make my life a bit easier, is there any way to sort the values in the vector to display all the values and their frequency?